# Why does the following makefile not work?

Tags: java, makefile

In the following makefile, the target "compile" is executed every single time irrespective of whether its dependencies are altered or not. The same however, is not true for the target "doc", although the dependencies are the same. Please help!

```
all : setup compile doc

setup : 
        @mkdir -p doc bin

compile: ./src/*.java ./src/cs296BookAnalysis/*.java
        @echo -n Compiling... 
        @javac -d ./bin ./src/cs296BookAnalysis/*.java ./src/BookAnalysisG01.java
        @echo Done!

doc: ./src/*.java ./src/cs296BookAnalysis/*.java
        @echo Generating Documentation using Javadoc... 
        @javadoc -d ./doc ./src/BookAnalysisG01.java -sourcepath ./src cs296BookAnalysis
        @echo Done!

clean: rm -rf doc bin
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because that's how makefiles work :-).

A makefile consists of *rules*: each block starting with a non-indented line is a rule. Each rule tells `make` how to create a certain file.

Normally, the part left of the ':' is the name of the generated file (the *target*). For example, for a C program you'd write:

```
main.o : main.c defs.h
    cc -c main.c
```

This tells `make`:

- this is a rule for how to create `main.o`
- `main.o` depends on `main.c` and `defs.h`
- run `cc ...` to create `main.o`

As a consequences, `make` will run the `cc...` part whenever

- `main.o` does not exist *or*
- `main.c` or `defs.h` are newer than `main.o`

Now, in your example the targets of the rules are not the files that are created. Such targets are called *phony targets*. Since `make` never finds these targets as files, the rules will run every time.

The `doc` rule is an exception: The directory `doc` actually exists, and since `javadoc` writes to this directory, the directory's timestamp will be updated. `make` will see that `doc` is newer than the source files, and will not run the rule.

---

That said, I strongly advise you **not to use Makefiles for compiling Java code**. While it is certainly possible, Makefiles are designed for C code, and lack many useful features for Java. Rather, **use a build tool for Java**. There are several available; I can recommend [Maven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven).

Answer (score 0):

try this and see .....

```
.Phony : abc 

doc : ./src/*.java ./src/cs296BookAnalysis/*.java  abc
        @echo Generating Documentation using Javadoc... 
        @javadoc -d ./doc ./src/BookAnalysisG01.java -sourcepath ./src cs296BookAnalysis
        @echo Done!

abc :
```

here abc is a false target that dosen't need to exist and wont get created since it has no prerequisites or recipie , it is used to force make to try to build the target abc and in the process the doc target will also appear as out of date .... thats what you wanted , doc target to be build each time you invoked "make all".